# RealityKit – Getting runtime warning when placing a model in ARView

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I get the following warning during runtime when I tap to load the model in ARView: Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'preliminary:anchoring:type' to a prim path (/)
Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'triggers' to a prim path (/)

Anyone have insights why I'm getting this warning? All of the logic is in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

private var modelArray: [String] = []
var selectedModel = ""

@IBOutlet weak var arView: ARView!

@IBOutlet weak var modelCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    loadModelName()
    arView.session.delegate = self
    setupARView()
    //modelArray = getModelNames()
    self.modelCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.modelCollectionView.delegate = self
    arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:))))
    
}
 // Dynamically load available files from directory
func loadModelName() {
    
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!

    do {
        let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

        for item in items where item.hasSuffix("usdz"){
            let modelName = item.replacingOccurrences(of: ".usdz", with: "")
            print("Found \(item)")
            modelArray.append(modelName)
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to read directory – bad permissions, perhaps?
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return modelArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath) as! itemCell
        cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: self.modelArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    selectedModel = self.modelArray[indexPath.row] + ".usdz"
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}



 func setupARView() {
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let configuration  = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh) {
            print("scene reconstruction supported")
            configuration.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
            configuration.sceneReconstruction = .meshWithClassification
            arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
        }
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        print("plane detection")
    }



 @objc
    func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //gets the location in the arView
        let location = recognizer.location(in: arView)
        //grab the results of the tap -location: the location of the tap -allowing: tye type of surface to calculate the location -alignment: the type of surface
        let reults = arView.raycast(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)
        
    //check to see if the raycast returned a result, did it actually hit a horizontal surface
    if let firstResult = reults.first {
        //returns an array of all the things it finds so grab the first
        //in order to add objects into a scene, we have to add objects to anchors, firstResult.worldTransform - add anchor at the orientation and position
        print("tap gesture recognized")
        print("DEBUG: the model is \(selectedModel)")
        let anchor = ARAnchor(name: selectedModel, transform: firstResult.worldTransform)
        arView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    } else {
        print("object placement failed, couldn't find surface")
    } 
}

func placeObject(named entityName: String, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
let entity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: entityName)

    //add collision to have physiscs for manipulations
    entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    arView.installGestures([.rotation, .translation], for: entity)

    //create an anchor entity
    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
    // add the entity to anchor
    anchorEntity.addChild(entity.clone(recursive: true))
    //add the anchor with the entity to the scene
    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
}
}

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        for anchor in anchors {
            if let anchorName = anchor.name, anchorName == selectedModel {
                placeObject(named: anchorName, for: anchor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the model you are adding a valid usdz file?

Comment: yes, they're usdz models from Apple

Comment: Hi @Myoung, have you tried my approach (I mean preliminary anchoring)?

Comment: Hi @AndyJazz no I've not tried yet as I'm working on some other projects but I will give it a try when I have a chance, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @AndyJazz I'm hoping you would know but for some reason after upgrading to latest software, both Xcode and iOS, I now am getting a message AR session failed when I launch my app (it compiles without errors) and it used to work previously before the updates.  Any idea what I should change? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Myoung, there are so many unpredictable errors in Xcode after each minor update, that I don't even know what to expect in the future and how to fix them ))

Comment: @AndyJazz ah! yeah, this is a problem.. :(  but thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: @AndyJazz I just upgraded to the latest iOS and it fixed the problem! I guess just keep updating till they fix the bugs.. :)

Answer (score 2):

### About Warnings

I will be brief, the answer sounds like this: ***if you setup a preliminary anchoring for USDZ model, then Xcode will not print such warnings***. Those warnings come from USD C++ library.

Now let's talk about this in more detail. As you said before, there are two warnings in Xcode's console when running your AR app in debug mode:

```
// Warning: in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp - Can only append a 
// property 'preliminary:anchoring:type' to a prim path (/)

// Warning: in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp - Can only append a
// property 'triggers' to a prim path (/)
```

You can easily find the C++ statement in Pixar/Apple `path.cpp` file (just type file's name in Spotlight Search string) that generates those warnings. Here it is:

```
SdfPath::AppendProperty(TfToken const &propName) const {
    if (ARCH_UNLIKELY(_propPart)) {
        TF_WARN("Can only append a property '%s' to a prim path (%s)",
                propName.GetText(), GetText());
        return EmptyPath();
    }
}
```

So, what's the point? Let me quote the Apple documentation:

> The [Preliminary_AnchoringAPI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/usdz_schemas_for_ar/preliminary_anchoringapi/preliminary_anchoring_type) specifies an anchor’s center as the prim’s origin, and the top of the anchor as its normal vector points. The runtime requires an asset to supply a value for this property.

---

You can read more about `preliminary:anchoring:type` in [USDZ Schemas](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-usdz-schemas-367ae40c6950) story.

---

In other words, if you use files with preliminary generated anchors in your scene, whether they are anchors assigned in Reality Composer or pythonically defined anchors for the `.usdz` scene, you will not receive such messages.

> [Reality Composer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/usdz_schemas_for_ar) describes AR features in its USDZ export using these schemas, too...

### Turning warnings off

If those messages are really annoying for you, just turn them off.

Go to Xcode's menu  <kbd>Product</kbd>  –  <kbd>Scheme</kbd>  –  <kbd>Edit Scheme</kbd>  and add you environment variable.

```
OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
```

[image]