# 3D model made in Blender not appearing on screen where expected

Tags: arkit, blender, realitykit, usdz

I created an object (a face) in Blender, exported it as a .obj, then used RealityConverter to make it a .usdz file.

I imported the .usdz file into my Xcode project. This is how I've attempted to anchor the Blender object to the user's face:

```
let cat = try! Entity.loadAnchor(named: "alienCat")
uiView.scene.addAnchor(cat)
```

When I use the above code with a simple object I created in Reality Composer, it works as expected and is anchored perfectly on the user's face.

But when I try the same code with my custom made .usdz file from Blender, the object doesn't appear on screen.

As I rotate the phone though, I see a large, blown up version floating above. I've attached 2 screenshots:

1. The camera facing my face, and my face is black (expected). But no object attached to my face (unexpected).

[image]

2. When I rotate the phone, I see my object floating way above my head and MUCH bigger than expected:
   [image]

When I run the code, this is the error I get in the Xcode console:

```
Warning: in AppendProperty at line 858 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'preliminary:anchoring:type' to a prim path (/)
Warning: in AppendProperty at line 858 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'triggers' to a prim path (/)
```

I believe my errors are originating from however I am creating my .obj in Blender. I'd like to fix these errors in Blender if possible. With the goal of just importing a .usdz and it works as expected. There was an answer posted here: [RealityKit – Getting runtime warning when placing a model in ARView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896647/realitykit-getting-runtime-warning-when-placing-a-model-in-arview) by Andy Jazz. And he says `If you setup a preliminary anchoring for USDZ model, then Xcode will not print such warnings.`

**Is there a way to set up this preliminary anchoring in Blender?**

**How do I get these errors removed and have my .usdz object placed on the face as expected, and in an appropriate size?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scaling issue

When exporting from Blender or Maya, the scale of the model is `100:1` by default (because you're exporting your model in centimeter scale, not RealityKit's [meter scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679940/realitykit-face-anchor-not-putting-model-in-ar/72682012#72682012)). Running facial tracking, the distance between the mask's pivot point and the mask surface is always greater than 0, which means that at a scale of `100:1`, this distance increases by hundred times. The pivot point can even be outside the bounding box of the model. Also check which Blender model's axis is facing up: positive Y or positive Z.

```
anchor.scale /= 100
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to export from blender at the correct size? Instead of having to make the adjustment in code?

Comment: Alan, here's a helpful link – https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/blender-units-vs-metric

Comment: You rule Andy. Thank you.